# Maven : I want to execute my junit test cases which resides in different folder structure

Tags: maven-3

My Junit test cases do not have conventional naming style like substring as TEST.
How to generate customized report using maven.
Below is my pom.xml

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>xxx.xxxx.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>suretest</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.1</version>
          <executions>
        <execution>
           <phase>test</phase>
             <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
             </goals>
               <configuration>
            <testSourceDirectory>my location where my junit testcasesare there</testSourceDirectory>
              <includes>
                <include>Weather.java</include>
                <include>Google.java</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
           </executions>
    </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
  </project>
```

Comment: First question: Why do you not the conventions and why are you using such an old version of maven-surefire-plugin (currently: 2.16)

Comment: Actually, i have used the 2.16 version but it is not working

Comment: Where are your test files located `src/test/java`? How have they been named like `xyzTest.java`? If you are using JUnit 4 you could use annotations for your tests `@Test`?

Comment: see my junit test files are located in different folder u can say xyz folder but not in default folder structure......and my test files are named as Weather.java and Google.java and at the same time i am not using Test as substring in name of my test files(Maven executes test files whose name contains Test as a substring)...........and i am using the @Test annotations also.....Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: The best solution is to follow the conventions. Name the test classes [according to the include rules of maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) furthermore put them into the default folder (`src/test/java`). This will make your life easier. Otherwise you have to configure the location via [`<testSourceDirectory>...</testSourceDirectory>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM). You have to change the include rule of maven surefire etc. The question: Is there any good reason why you don't follow the conventions?

Comment: Ohk i will use the conventions as per the maven guidelines.But i am also not able to generate the customize html report.Could you please provideme the solution.I am new to maven.

Comment: Fix first this step. Use an other question about the reporting.

Comment: My test cases are running but the reports are not generating....